# Showing Stability of a PDE Solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian

I am asked to show that a problem of Laplace's Equation is well-posed in terms of stability with respect to small changes in the initial data. The PDE is:

> $$u_{tt}+u_{xx} =0,\>\>\>\>\>\> u(x,0) = 0,\>\>\>\> u_t(x,0)=\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$$

We are given the solution:
$$u_n(x,t) = \frac{\sinh(nt)\sin(nx)}{n^2}$$
Thus we have to find out what happens to the solution at a later fixed time t. Since the solution grows exponentially, I figured that the solution wouldn't change much when $n$ is low, but as $n$ became large, there would be a lot of volatility with respect to small changes in the initial data. But how can I show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to look at the homogeneous version for your problem, say it's solution is $v(x, t)$. Then you should be able to say something about $|v_{t}(x,0) - u_{t}(x,0)|$ and $|v(x, t) - u(x, t)|$. That is, the difference in the initial conditions should result in large differences in the solution when $n$ is large.

EDIT:

Following from the comments,

$\frac{\sinh{nt}\sin{nx}}{n^2} = \frac{(e^{nt}-e^{-nt})\sin{nx}}{2n^2} = \frac{(e^{nt}\sin{nx}-e^{-nt}\sin{nx})}{2n^2}$

For large n, the $e^{nt}$ term dominates the entire expression, so it will diverge. The second term goes to zero, and even dividing by $2n^2$ cannot outweigh how fast the exponential term grows.

Comment: I was told that all I had to do was take the limit of the solution as $n\rightarrow\infty$, with $t$ fixed. But I have no idea how to compute the limit.

Comment: You already described the behavior of the limit in your post, however you are asked to show that the problem is ILL posed. When n is large the initial condition is very small, close to 0, now what happens to the solution when n is large? It's blows up.

Comment: Sorry when $n$ is large the initial condition is small or it blows up?

Comment: When $n$ is big, $\frac{\sin{nx}}{n}$ is extremely oscillatory and close to 0, do you believe that? Hence, you can view it as a small change in the initial condition from the homogeneous version of your problem. 

Now, based on that, what happens to your solution when $n$ is big? You should be able to show that 

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sinh{nt}\sin{nx}}{n^2}$$ diverges to infinity.

Comment: I'm trying l'Hopitals rule and Taylor Series but can't seem to prove it. What method do you recommend?

Comment: I edited my solution to give some intuition about the limit. You must treat $t$ and $x$ as constants when evaluating it, because the limit only has anything to do with $n$.